# How to print profile id associated with the user in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, profile

I need to print profile id (pid) of the logged in user. User id and profile id is a different number, but they are correltaed in the profile table in database. Any idea how can i do it?

Comment: Since this is Drupal 7, is this profile or profile 2?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name = NULL). Worst-case scenario, you can always db_query from the database.